# How to export Oracle Apex Application dynamically?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to export an Oracle Apex app

```
    variable AppId number
    begin
        select application_id into :AppId FROM apex_applications where alias = 'SOMEALIAS'; 
    end;
    /

    print AppId

    apex export -applicationid AppId;
```

This script shows a valid app id in the line **print AppId** however the export statement returns the following error :

```
    Invalid Workspace ID null
```

If I do manually :

```
    apex export -applicationid 1116;
```

It works.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Have a look at my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70571785/exporting-all-oracle-apex-applications-using-sqlcl

Comment: @KoenLostrie your solution is magical. It works like charm. Thanks but what is this language ? Where to find any documentation about it ?

Comment: Google "sqlcl script" or "sqlcl scripting". Lots of info and links to samples [here](https://github.com/mennooo/SQLcl) on Menno's page. The language or dialect is Nashorn. Note it is not included in the latest java versions (Jeff Smitsh blog has an article about that)